# How do I sort_index, groupby and apply a function in Dask?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, dask

I have a function that is applied over a pandas dataframe, I am considering using dask to improve performance

This is my existing code:

```
df.reset_index(
        level=0,
        inplace=True,
    )

df = df.sort_index().groupby(
            ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
            as_index=False).apply(
        myfunction
    )
```

I am trying to convert this to the dask syntax and managed to get to:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

nCores = cpu_count()

df = dd.from_pandas(
        df,
        npartitions=nCores
    ).reset_index().set_index().groupby(
        ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
        ).apply(
            myfunction
        ).compute()
```

It appears you can only pass a column to `set_index` and there is no equivalent of `sort_index()` in dask. How can I write this pandas code in the dask syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in a similar solution, here is a version of the code in the dask syntax that works, please note that I sort the index before passing it to dask.

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

nCores = cpu_count()

df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df = dd.from_pandas(
        df,
        npartitions=nCores
    ).map_partitions(
        lambda df : df.groupby(
            ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
            ).apply(
                my_function
            )
        ).compute()
```

Importantly, the dask version was not faster than the pandas approach; but comes very close. The `my_function` in this case is vectorised and is applied to each groupby object primarily using numpy arrays.